# Gradle refresh failed (Error : no route to host) -> Android studio in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu

We have java 8 installed in ubuntu. And followed documentations said by google android studio. When we create new project gradle runs for some time and get failed. Following is a error

Gradle Refresh failed.

> Error: no route to host.

[link for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75e1S.png)

[Screenshot of gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO5ff.png)

Comment: Can you please share the content of your build.gradle file?

Comment: @AmauryMedeiros please look at screen shot of gradle

Comment: @AmauryMedeiros https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO5ff.png gradle screenshot

Comment: Try refactoring your package... don't use underscores (i.e. "_")

Comment: @AmauryMedeiros Oh god.. thanks buddy :) It is working fine now. Lot of time we had spent on this.

Answer (score 2):

Just Run Android Studio

[File]-->[Invalidate Caches/Restart] --> choose [Invalidate and Restart]

wait a moment...

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate Caches/Restart not work for me. I found the global gradle.properties file there are some url that are not valid, I just delete them. (for Mac, the file should be in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties)